# How to limit thumb gallery display of blueimp jquery file upload per user or IP?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

tips on how to do this would be great.  I'm a jQuery newbie.  Here's the [jquery file upload demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

I need to limit the display of the thumb gallery row per user instance. I don't really know the best way to do that, and am open to suggestions.

I would guess that options would be
:: create an ID per visited IP and somehow create a variable with that IP and only display thumb gallery row if IP matches
:: or declare a cookie, and match the cookie

Thanks --Sandra

Answer (score 0):

I went the cookie way using [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) cookieCreate and cookieRead functions altered to the hour (rather than days).  The value of the cookie is a 5-digit alphanumeric string (script based on this [forum](http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-40859.html)).

The function for the cookie value is below, though the functions to create and read the cookie you'll have to fetch from quirksmode with the link provided above as I did not copy them here.  Hope this helps someone.  FYI, the "cheese" is the value of the cookie.

Alter upload.class.php (in server/php directory) and add a line after Line 217.  Line 217 is

```
$file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
```

Add a line altering the filename as follows

```
$file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
// add filename prefix
$file_name = $_COOKIE['user'].'_'.$file_name;
```

Then, to display only files for that user, edit your html file as follows

Original code

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
```

Edited code

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
{% grab_the_cheese = file.name.split('_'); %}
{% if (grab_the_cheese[0] == cheese) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
```

and close the if at the bottom

original

```
     </tr>
 {% } %}
```

edited

```
     </tr>
 {%  } /* cheese */ %}
 {% } %}
```

The 5-digit alphanumeric string function below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// generate a cookie
chars = new Array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'); 
charCount = chars.length;
stringLength = 5; 
var outputString = ''; 
function mkRandomString() { 
   i = 0; 
   do { 
      random = Math.floor(Math.random()*56); 
      random = chars[random]; 
      outputString += String(random); 
      i++; 
   } 
   while (i<stringLength); 
   return outputString;
} 

// set a cookie
//var cheese = document.cookie;
createCookie('user',mkRandomString(),1);
var cheese = readCookie('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, jQuery File Uploads allows you to do this in a single line.
You just have to add 'user_dirs' => true in the construct of your upload handler. Then, you can override get_user_id() to return your system's id (instead of the default, which is session_id).

The best thing about this method is that it doesn't rely on an cookie that a user can manipulate easily.

see https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories